# Send mp3 as blob by clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, blob

I have button here `Material-UI`

```
    <Button><a id="downloadLink">
      <i onClick = {() => this.download()} id="dlBtn" class="fas fa-ex fa-download"></i></a>
    </Button>
```

in Javascript

```
download(){
   //my mp3 file is http://localhost/mp3/my.mp3
   //I want to send the mp3 file to user when cliking download button
  link.href = "http://localhost/mp3/my.mp3";
  link.innerText = 'Myfile.mp3';
  var dlBox = document.getElementById("downloadLink");
  dlBox.appendChild(link);
}
```

After clicking button download doesn't work.

I guess I should use `blob` though, I am not sure how.
Please help me to understand.

Comment: `http://localhost/mp3/mp.mp3`  with two `//` characters after the hostname.

Comment: Thank you that's typo